# Field type that is an integer, but accept some strings that means no value is provided?

Tags: entities

I have a field named "Price" that should allow anything from 0 - no maximum value, so I set it as an Integer and set 0 for the minimum value (and put a suffix to show up for the price).

However, the field contented is generated by parsing a JSON feed, and the feed owner sometimes puts "on demand" for some items, meaning the price can be negotiated on demand or the price is private and only shared when a client shows enough interest to buy.
The [Feeds JSONPath Parser](https://drupal.org/project/feeds_jsonpath_parser) module parses the text string and doesn't import the fields with text for the Price field as it's not an Integer. Therefore resulting in a blank field input.

Should I replace all empty values with a 0 and then on view results set 0 to be rewritten to the "on demand" text? Or is there another way that I should explore?

I need to keep the Price field as an Integer since I use it for a range filter in my view.

Comment: Are those the only 2 variations? Either an integer or "on demand"? There's no other status like "free" or "POA" etc?

Comment: @Beebee nope just that it seems for now, it's for apartments/houses to rent or buy, so I assume sometimes they want to keep the price private?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have only one possible non-integer value, leave it as integer, just make it optional (not required). As far as I understand Feeds JSONPath Parser, non-integer value will simply get omitted, giving you no value for this field - exactly consistent as in fact you don't have that price.

Then in your template files check if it's set. If it isn't, show "on demand" string, with a link to make a demand or, well, anything you need.

Comment: Ah yes I'll need to edit my templates too, forgot about those.